# Will the last electrical receptacle on the same circuit have two cables entering the box?

Tags: electrical

I have identified three receptacles in my garage coming from the same circuit breaker. All three boxes have two romex cables entering the boxes.  There appear to be no other devices on this breaker.

Why would the last outlet receptacle on this circuit have two cables entering its box if it is the end of the run?

Comment: What is on the other end of each of the two cables? Presumably one goes to the previous outlet box, where does the other one go?

Comment: Most likely it does feed something else. Or is there more to this circuit like a switch or something?

Answer (score 3):

Then it's not the last *outlet*.

An *outlet* is any point of use, i.e. an overhead light or hardwired exhaust fan.  A *receptacle* is the fancy name for the familiar socket.  A receptacle is one type of outlet.

And it's not *n* cables entering the box.  It's 1 cable entering the box and *n-1* cables exiting the box to go to downline load(s).  *n* can be 3 or more, by the way.

Every load must attach at a junction box or fixture that must be accessible without disassembling the house in any way (other than the fixture itself, obviously).  So there should never be a need to unscrew wood panels, bust up and re-mud drywall, etc.  Between accessible points there can only be wires.

So if you take covers off things, and remove lamps etc., you should be able to find it.   There are electronic tools which can aid in the search greatly.

Comment: Yep, I would look for device not typical and hardly used. My best guess would be the attic or outdoor receptacles.